# Check if there is an isomorph substring

Tags: code-golf

This question is an extension of [Check if words are isomorphs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50472/check-if-words-are-isomorphs)  and copies the first part of it to give the definition of an isomorph.

Two words are *[isomorphs](http://www.questrel.com/records.html#spelling_structure_entire_word_isomorph_or_matching_letter_pattern)* if they have the same pattern of letter repetitions. For example, both `ESTATE` and `DUELED` have pattern `abcdca`

```
ESTATE
DUELED

abcdca
```

because letters 1 and 6 are the same, letters 3 and 5 are the same, and nothing further. This also means the words are related by a substitution cipher, here with the matching `E <-> D, S <-> U, T <-> E, A <-> L`.

Given two strings X and Y, with X no longer than Y, the task is to determine if there is a substring of Y which is an isomorph with X.

**Input:** Two non-empty strings of letters from a..zA..Z which one string per line.  This will come from standard input.

**Output** A substring of the second string which is an isomorph with the first string, if such a thing exists. Otherwise output "No!".

**Rules** Your code must run in linear time in the total length of the input.

**Score** Your score is the number of bytes in your code.  Fewest bytes wins.

---

**Example input and output**

```
adca
ddaddabdaabbcc

dabd
```

**Tip**

There is at least one not *that* complicated, practically fast and linear time solution to this problem.

Comment: @AlexA. I think someone told me that if you restrict the running time/complexity then it should be code-challenge. I am happy to change it if that is wrong of course.

Comment: If the run time is bounded by a rule and does not influence the scoring, code-golf is a better fit than code-challenge.

Comment: linear time means it needs to be O(m+n) and not O(m x n) nor O(m x (n-m)) where m, n are length of first and 2nd string?

Comment: @someuser Yes it means  O(m+n) .

Comment: Are the two input strings of equal length? If not, could you give some examples with their respective outputs?

Comment: @BetaDecay See "Given two strings X and Y, with X no longer than Y, the task is to determine if there is a substring of Y which is an isomorph with X."

Comment: I think the idea of KMP algorithm should still work. But I'm too lazy to golf a piece of code using 6 arrays together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Python 2, <s>338</s> <s>326</s> <s>323</s> <s>321</s> <s>310</s> <s>306</s> <s>297</s> <s>293</s> <s>290</s> <s>289</s> <s>280</s> <s>279</s> <s>266</s> <s>264</s> <s>259</s> <s>237</s> <s>230</s> <s>229</s> <s>226</s> <s>223</s> <s>222</s> <s>220</s> <s>219</s> 217 (<s>260</s> <s>238</s> <s>231</s> <s>228</s> <s>225</s> <s>223</s> <s>221</s> <s>220</s> 218 with 0 exit status)

```
exec'''s=raw_input()
S=[M-s.rfind(c,0,M)for M,c in enumerate(s)]
k=0
j=x=%s
while k<=M+x:
 if S[k]>j<W[j]or S[k]==W[j]:
    k+=1;j+=1;T+=[j]
    if j-L>x:print s[k-j:k];z
 else:j=T[j]
'''*2%('-1;T=[0];W=S;L=M',0)
print'No!'
```

The algorithm is a variation of KMP, using an index-based test for character matching. The basic idea is that if we get a mismatch at position `X[i]` then we can fall back to the next possible place for a match according to the longest suffix of `X[:i]` that is isomorphic to a prefix of `X`.

Working from left to right, we assign each character an index equal to the distance to the most recent previous occurrence of that character, or if there is no previous occurrence then we take the length of the current string prefix. For example:

```
MISSISSIPPI
12313213913
```

To test whether two characters match, we compare indices, adjusting appropriately for indices that are greater than the length of the current (sub)string.

The KMP algorithm becomes a little simplified since we cannot get a mismatch on the first character.

This program outputs the first match if one exists. I use a runtime error to exit in the event of a match, but the code can be easily modified to exit cleanly at the cost of some bytes.

**Note:** For computing indices, we can use `str.rfind` (as opposed to my earlier approach using a dictionary) and still have linear complexity, assuming that `str.rfind` starts searching from the end (which seems the only sane implementation choice) -- for each character in the alphabet, we never have to traverse the same part of the string twice, so there is an upper bound of (size of alphabet) * (size of string) comparisons.

Since the code got fairly obfuscated in the course of golfing, here is an earlier (293 byte) solution that's a bit easier to read:

```
e=lambda a:a>i<W[i]or a==W[i]
exec('s=raw_input();S=[];p={};M=i=0\nfor c in s:S+=[M-p.get(c,-1)];p[c]=M;M+=1\nW=S;L=M;'*2)[:-9]
T=[0]*L
k=1
while~k+L:
 if e(W[k]):i+=1;k+=1;T[k]=i
 else:i=T[i]
m=i=0
while m+i<M:
 if e(S[m+i]):
    if~-L==i:print s[m:m+L];z
    i+=1
 else:m+=i-T[i];i=T[i]
print'No!'
```

The `e` function tests equivalence of characters. The `exec` statement assigns indices and does some variable initialisations. The first loop processes `X` for fall back values, and the second loop does the string search.

**Update:** Here is a version that exits cleanly, at the cost of one byte:

```
r='No!'
exec'''s=raw_input()
S=[M-s.rfind(c,0,M)for M,c in enumerate(s)]
k=0
j=x=%s
while k<=M+x:
 if S[k]>j<W[j]or S[k]==W[j]:
    k+=1;j+=1;T+=[j]
    if j-L>x:r=k=s[k-j:k]
 else:j=T[j]
'''*2%('-1;T=[0];W=S;L=M',0)
print r
```

Comment: I think you can save a byte by doing python3. `r=raw_input` vs. r=`input` saves 4 bytes and the parens on print only cost 3.

Comment: @Maltysen thanks for the comment. I didn't consider Python 3 when writing this, but as for cost and savings, there is an additional 2 byte cost since you can't mix spaces and tabs for indentation in Python 3.

Comment: @Maltysen just to follow up, the issue is now no longer tabs but brackets for `exec`.

Comment: This is a really great answer! I look forward to seeing it in cjam now :)

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, 401 bytes

```py
import string,itertools
X=input()
Y=input()
x=len(X)
t=[-1]+[0]*~-x
j=2
c=0
while j<x:
 if X[j-1]==X[c]:c+=1;t[j]=c;j+=1
 elif c>0:c=t[c]
 else:t[j]=0;j+=1
s=string.ascii_letters
*b,=map(s.find,X)
for p in itertools.permutations(s):
 m=i=0
 while m+i<len(Y):
  if p[b[i]]==Y[m+i]:
   if~-x==i:print(Y[m:m+x]);exit()
   else:i+=1
  else:
   if-1<t[i]:m+=i-t[i];i=t[i]
   else:i=0;m+=1
else:print("No!")
```

This is still mostly ungolfed, but I think it should work. The core algorithm is [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), plus an additional factor which is factorial in the size of the alphabet (which is fine, since the alphabet is constant). In other words, this is/should be one completely impractical linear algorithm.

Here's a few annotations to help with the analysis:

```py
# KMP failure table for the substring, O(n)
t=[-1]+[0]*~-x
j=2
c=0
while j<x:
 if X[j-1]==X[c]:c+=1;t[j]=c;j+=1
 elif c>0:c=t[c]
 else:t[j]=0;j+=1

# Convert each char to its index in a-zA-Z, O(alphabet * n)
s=string.ascii_letters
*b,=map(s.find,X)

# For every permutation of letters..., O(alphabet!)
for p in itertools.permutations(s):
 # Run KMP, O(n)
 m=i=0
 while m+i<len(Y):
  if p[b[i]]==Y[m+i]:
   if~-x==i:print(Y[m:m+x]);exit()
   else:i+=1
  else:
   if-1<t[i]:m+=i-t[i];i=t[i]
   else:i=0;m+=1
else:print("No!")
```

For testing, you can replace `s` with a smaller alphabet than `string.ascii_letters`.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 32 bytes

This is an infix function, taking X as left argument and Y as right argument.

```apl
{(s,⊂'No!')⊃⍨(⍳⍨¨s←⍵,/⍨≢⍺)⍳⊂⍳⍨⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P7P4UduEao1inUddTep@@Yrqmo@6mh/1rtB41LsZSB1aAZJ/1LtVRx/Ie9S56FHvLk2QVFcTRAGQX/v/v3piSnKiukJmsYJ6SkoiECWlJCYmJSUnq3OBpFKwSgEA)

`{`…`}` anonymous lambda where `⍺` and `⍵` represent the arguments (X and Y)

`⍳⍨⍺` **ɩ**ndex selfie of X (**ɩ**ndices of the first occurrence of elements of X in X)

`⊂` enclose so we can look for that entire pattern

`(`…`)⍳` **ɩ**ndex of first occurrence of that in…

`≢⍺` tally (length) of X

`⍵,/⍨` all substrings of that size of Y (lit. concatenation reduction of those, but that is a no-op)

`s←` store in `s` (for **s**ubstrings)

`⍳⍨¨` **ɩ**ndex selfie of each of those

now we have the index of the first pattern, or 1 + the number of patterns if no match was found

`(`…`)⊃⍨` use that index to pick from…

`⊂'No!'` the enclosed string (so that it functions as a single element)

`s,` prepended with `s`