# Sign that word!

Tags: code-golf, string, sorting, word

## What is a Word Signature?

The signature of a word are all of it's letters put in order - the signatures of `this`, `hist` and `hits` are all `hist`.

## The Challenge

Write a program program should ask for an input, then print out the signature of that word. So an example program run might look like this:

```
Give me a string: this
The signature signature of 'this' is hist.
```

There is no required interaction, as long as it takes an input and prints the signature, it is OK.

## Scoring

The program with the smallest byte count wins!

## Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=54945;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),e.has_more?getAnswers():process()}})}function shouldHaveHeading(e){var a=!1,r=e.body_markdown.split("\n");try{a|=/^#/.test(e.body_markdown),a|=["-","="].indexOf(r[1][0])>-1,a&=LANGUAGE_REG.test(e.body_markdown)}catch(n){}return a}function shouldHaveScore(e){var a=!1;try{a|=SIZE_REG.test(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0])}catch(r){}return a}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){answers=answers.filter(shouldHaveScore).filter(shouldHaveHeading),answers.sort(function(e,a){var r=+(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[1/0])[0],n=+(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[1/0])[0];return r-n});var e={},a=1,r=null,n=1;answers.forEach(function(s){var t=s.body_markdown.split("\n")[0],o=jQuery("#answer-template").html(),l=(t.match(NUMBER_REG)[0],(t.match(SIZE_REG)||[0])[0]),c=t.match(LANGUAGE_REG)[1],i=getAuthorName(s);l!=r&&(n=a),r=l,++a,o=o.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",i).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",c).replace("{{SIZE}}",l).replace("{{LINK}}",s.share_link),o=jQuery(o),jQuery("#answers").append(o),e[c]=e[c]||{lang:c,user:i,size:l,link:s.share_link}});var s=[];for(var t in e)e.hasOwnProperty(t)&&s.push(e[t]);s.sort(function(e,a){return e.lang>a.lang?1:e.lang<a.lang?-1:0});for(var o=0;o<s.length;++o){var l=jQuery("#language-template").html(),t=s[o];l=l.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",t.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",t.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",t.size).replace("{{LINK}}",t.link),l=jQuery(l),jQuery("#languages").append(l)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",answers=[],page=1;getAnswers();var SIZE_REG=/\d+(?=[^\d&]*(?:&lt;(?:s&gt;[^&]*&lt;\/s&gt;|[^&]+&gt;)[^\d&]*)*$)/,NUMBER_REG=/\d+/,LANGUAGE_REG=/^#*\s*([^,]+)/;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table></div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table></div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

**Challenged Finished!**

**WINNER: [jimmy23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54947/42003)**

Comment: We don't have to print the sentences `Give me a string:` and `The signature signature of 'this' is` right? We can just take the input directly and print the result?

Comment: Also are inputs consisting only of lowercase characters or can there be uppercase letters?

Comment: What about duplicate letters? e.g. is the signature of `broom` `bmoor` or `bmor`?

Comment: @Fatalize Yes, there is no required interaction with the user. Just take the input and print the result.

Comment: @samgak bmoor. Duplicates are put in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad/trivial.

Comment: @isaacg why are you?

Comment: This looks essentially like a duplicate of [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50472/194).

Comment: @Tim I don't think we should have challenges that are this straightforward. I'll ask about it on meta - it's not really about this question in particular.

Comment: Well, I'm a few hours late, and every competitive language I know has already been done. :/

Comment: I think this would have been a more interesting challenge if you couldn't use built-in sorting functions.

Comment: @GlenO, or duplicate letters and multicase need to be supported.

Comment: @JamesWebster Duplicate letters do.

Comment: These suggestions will be addressed in Sign that word 2, being posted soon. That one will have a stricter set of rules.

Comment: Added second edition. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55090/sign-that-word-2 Not a duplicate because the answers from this question are **not** transposable to that one.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## GolfScript, 1 byte

```
$
```

Yes, only 1 byte.

[Try it here.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJ0aGlzIiAjIE92ZXJyaWRlIHN0ZGluCgok)

Comment: Marked as correct because no-one can beat 1 byte.

Comment: @Kslkgh In theory, maybe someone can find a language that can do it in 0 bytes?

Comment: OK then, fair enough, will mark as correct in 1 week!

Comment: SERIOUSLY?!    _____

Comment: I would say that this fails for "Hello"

Comment: Seems to break for anything with a capital, but guess it was never specified

Comment: Capitals don't break the code.  It first sorts capitals then lowercase.  i.e. cbaCBAfed -> ABCabcdef

Comment: Congratulations to @jimmy23013, you win!

Answer (score 26):

## C (with x86), 61 bytes

```
s[];main(){qsort(s,read(0,s,99),1,"YXZQQQ\x8a\x00*\x02\x0f\xbe\xc0\xc3");puts(s);}
```

That string contains raw bytes, not actual `\x..` codes, and it's a *raw machine code callback* passed to `qsort`. Works on x86 only:

```
59         pop   ecx
58         pop   eax
5a         pop   edx
51         push  ecx
51         push  ecx
51         push  ecx
8a 00      mov   al,  BYTE PTR [eax]
2a 02      sub   al,  BYTE PTR [edx]
0f be c0   movsx eax, al
c3         ret
```

Which is essentially:

```
int func(char *a, char *b) { return *a - *b; }
```

See p6-7 of this [pamphlet in Japanese by shinh](http://shinh.skr.jp/dat_dir/golf_prosym.pdf).

Comment: This is not generic C language, as it targets a specific architecture. That should be specified in the heading

Answer (score 20):

## Stuck, 4 bytes

```
sc$d
```

[This language](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Stuck) was documented on the wiki just yesterday! Mmm, fresh esolangs.

Comment: Nicely done! :)

Answer (score 19):

## Stuck, 5 Bytes

I finally get to use my language, [Stuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Stuck)! :D

```
s$""j
```

This takes an input via stdin, sorts, joins, and implicitly prints. This did give me some ideas for changes though.

**Edit:** Oh wow, someone already posted and beat me in my own language!

Answer (score 16):

## GOTO++, <s>432</s> 430 bytes

[GOTO++ project site](http://www.gotopp.org/).

```
niveaugourou 0
s=ENTRETONTEXTE()
§2 a=LeCaracNumero()&s *(1)
n=*(1)
costaud i=*(2)/&i infeg NombreDeLettres(&s)/i=+*(1)
b=LeCaracNumero()&s &i
GOTONULPOURLESNULS %1 }&b inf &a{
a=&b
n=&i
§1 faiblard
GOTOPRINTDUTEXTE()&a
t=PrendsUnMorceau()&s *(0) &n
u=PrendsUnMorceau()&s }&n+*(1){ *(0)
e=BOITEAPINGOUINS()&t &u
s=Marijuana()&e «»
GOTONONNULPOURLESNULS %3 }NombreDeLettres(&s) eg *(1){
GOTOPASMALIN %2
§3 GOTOPRINTDUTEXTE()&s
```

Not sure why I inflicted this to myself, but I did

Answer (score 13):

## gs2, 1 byte

```
/
```

Same as the GolfScript answer, but [gs2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2) uses a different operator for sorting.

Answer (score 10):

## Perl, 18 bytes

```
print sort<>=~/./g
```

Thanks to Dom Hastings for helping me save 3 bytes.

Comment: you can save a few bytes using a `/./g` instead of `split'',`: `print sort<>=~/./g`!

Comment: With `-nE`, you can do `say sort/./g`.

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell, 35 bytes

```
import Data.List;main=interact sort
```

Answer (score 6):

## C#, <s>114</s> 110 characters

Takes input from a command line argument. Not a very short program, but well... it's C#. :P

```c#
namespace System.Linq{class P{static void Main(string[]a){Console.Write(string.Concat(a[0].OrderBy(x=>x)));}}}
```

Thanks to Abbas for saving 4 bytes!

Comment: You can save 4 chars by using `Write` instead of `WriteLine`. ;)

Comment: @Abbas Thanks! Totally missed that one ;p

Answer (score 6):

### Pyth, 2 bytes

```
Sw
```

[DEMO HERE.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Sw&input=this&debug=0)
Details-

```
S - for sorting
w - Python 3's input()
```

Answer (score 6):

## J, 3 bytes

```
/:~
```

For example: `/:~'this'`

Answer (score 6):

## Brainfuck, 40 bytes

```
,[>>+>>,]<<[[<<]>>[-[<]>>[.<<->]>+>>]<<]
```

This uses the [counting sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), which makes this an **O(n)** solution.

The code requires a left-infinite or wrapping tape of 8 bit cells. [Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LFs-Pis-PixdPDxbWzw8XT4-Wy1bPF0-PlsuPDwtPl0-Kz4-XTw8XQ&input=UHJvZ3JhbW1pbmcgUHV6emxlcyAmIENvZGUgR29sZg)

#### How it works

```
,          Read a char from STDIN.
[          While the byte under the pointer (last read char) is non-zero:
  >>+        Move the pointer two steps to the right and increment.
  >>,        Move the pointer two steps to the right and read a char.
]
<<         Move the pointer two steps to the left.

           If the input was "sort", the tape now contains the following:
           0 0 115 0 1 0 111 0 1 0 114 0 1 0 116 0 1 0 0
                                                   ^

[          While the byte under the pointer is non-zero:
  [<<]       Advance two steps to the left until a null byte is encountered.
  >>         Advance two steps to the right.

             This will place the pointer on the first input character.

  [          While the byte under the pointer is non-zero:
    -          Decrement.
    [<]        Move the pointer to the left until a null byte is encountered.
    >>         Move the pointer two steps to the right.

               If the decremented character is non-zero, [<] will move to the
               null byte before it, so >> brings the pointer to the null byte
               after it. If the decremented character is zero, [<] is a no-op, so
               >> advances two steps to the right, to a non-zero byte.

    [          While the byte under the pointer is non-zero:
      .          Print the char under the pointer.
      <<-        Move the pointer two steps to the left and decrement.
      >          Move the pointer to the right.
    ]

               If the decremented character gave zero, this will print the value
               of the accumulator after it, and decrement the character once more
               to make it non-zero, then place the pointer to the right of the
               character, thus exiting the loop.

    >+         Move the pointer to the right and increment.

               This increments the accumulator each time an input character is
               decremented.

    >>         Move the pointer two steps to the right.

               This moves the pointer to the next character.
  ]
  <<         Move the pointer two steps to the left.

             This moves the pointer to the accumulator of the last character.
]

             After 255, th accumulator wraps around to 0, and the loop ends.
```

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, 2 bytes

```
l$
```

Reads a line of input (`l`) and sorts it (`$`).

Answer (score 4):

### Coreutils, <strike>24</strike> 23

```
fold -w1|sort|tr -d \\n
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3, 31 Bytes

```
print("".join(sorted(input())))
```

Comment: That looks like 29 bytes to me

Comment: @muddyfish it's 31 chars, when I counted :)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 17 bytes

```
$><<$<.chars.sort
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, 119 bytes

This is basically only competitive with the C# answer, because, well, Java.

(At least this beats GOTO++. Not really an accomplishment...)

```
class C{public static void main(String[]s){s=s[0].split("");java.util.Arrays.sort(s);System.out.print("".join("",s));}}
```

*Thanks to ProgramFOX for saving 1 byte, rink.attendant for saving 2 bytes.*

Comment: You can save one char by removing the space between `String[]` and `s`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that. Now my byte count is a nice square number. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can use `System.out.print` instead of `println`

Comment: Thank you! This is my first attempt at code golf, so I still have to learn stuff like that.

Comment: You could save 12 characters with `public static void main(String[]s){s[0].chars().sorted().forEach(i->System.out.print((char)i));}`

Answer (score 4):

## Ostrich, 2 bytes

```
G$
```

In [Ostrich](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/ostrich-lang) `G` reads a line of input from STDIN and `$` sorts it.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 32 bytes

Demo only works in Firefox and Edge at time of writing, as Chrome/Opera does not support ES6 by default:

Edit: I didn't look at the answers prior to posting but now I realize it's pretty much the exact same as [the one by NinjaBearMonkey](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54988/22867).

```js
f=x=>alert([...x].sort().join``)
```

```html
<form action=# onsubmit='f(document.getElementById("I").value);return false;'>
  <input type=text pattern=\w+ id=I>
  <button type=submit>Sort letters</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 21 bytes

```
s->join(sort([s...]))
```

And for fun, here's how you might do it without using an inbuilt sorting function, for 53 bytes:

```
f=s->s>""?(k=indmax(s);f(s[k+1:end]s[1:k-1])s[k:k]):s
```

Answer (score 2):

## SWI-Prolog, 34 bytes

```
a(X):-msort(X,Y),writef("%s",[Y]).
```

Called as such:`` a(`this`). ``

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 21 bytes

```
print(args(0).sorted)
```

run from command line example:

```
$ scala -e "print(args(0).sorted)" this
hist
```

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>44</s> 37 Bytes

```
-join((Read-Host).ToCharArray()|sort)
```

Comment: also +1 for powershell use, but i beatcha :)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 34 bytes

```js
alert([...prompt()].sort().join``)
```

The reason this is so long is that JavaScript can only sort arrays, so the string must be split into an array, sorted, and then joined back into a string. This is ECMAScript 6; the equivalent in ES5 is:

```js
alert(prompt().split('').sort().join(''))
```

Comment: Should specify EcmaScript 6 as it's using `...` and template strings

Comment: @edc65 You're right, I forgot. Done.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <strike>33</strike> 32 bytes

```
print`sorted(raw_input())`[2::5]
```

Heavily inspired by @Kamehameha's answer. Converted to python 2. Can't golf much more.

Comment: You can use `repr` to bring it down another byte (Now you know why I chose Python 3 version of the solution :P) - `print\`sorted(raw_input())\`[2::5]` (Those are backticks, not single quotes)

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 7 characters

Doesn't work on ngn-apl for me, but should work in theory:

```
X[⍋X←⍞]
```

`⍞` reads a line from standard input, which is assigned to `X`. `⍋X` is the indices of `X` which yield an ascending order, and `X[...]` actually sorts `X` by these indices.

Comment: Works on Dyalog (desktop version, not TryAPL).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 54 bytes

call js file with node

```
console.log(process.argv[2].split('').sort().join(''))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Nim, <s>102</s> <s>101</s> <s>79</s> 73 bytes

```nim
let s=stdin.readAll
for i in 1..'~':
 for j in s:(if i==j:stdout.write j)
```

Still learning Nim and working out golf tricks. Apparently it's better *not* to use the builtin `sort`, which would require a lot of imports (thanks @Mauris)

Comment: `let s=stdin.readAll;for i in 1..'~':(for j in s:(if i==j:echo j))` is 65 bytes.

Comment: @Mauris Wow, I didn't think that not using the builtin sort would be shorter! Only problem though - is there a way to `echo` without the trailing newline?

Comment: Oh, oops, of course. `stdout.write j` seems to work, and is slightly shorter than your `&=` loop.

Comment: @Mauris Indeed, it seems to work - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab, <s>13</s> 5 bytes

The code simply defines a function handle to the `sort` function:

```
@sort
```

To call it, use `ans('this')`, where `'this'` represents the input string (thanks to Alex A. and Stewie Griffin):

```
>> @sort
ans = 
    @sort
>> ans('this')
ans =
hist
```

Comment: Gotta love `f('this')`. I don't think you need to count the name of the function in your byte count though, since unnamed functions are generally acceptable.

Comment: @AlexA Thanks! But if I define the function without the function handle `f` , i.e. just `@(x)sort(x)`, then the call can't (obviously) be `f('this')`. It needs to be the uglier and cumbersome `feval(@(x)sort(x),'this')`. Do you think that would be acceptable?

Comment: Yep, that's very common. Often folks just say, "to call the function give it a name."

Comment: I don't like this _at all_, but you can actually do: `@(x)sort(x)`, and then `ans('this')`. I guess you don't need to count the bytes for `ans`..? Obviously this only works one time, but nothing in the rules prevent this. Also, I would claim `sort('this')` should suffice, seeing that everyone else just uses the built in sort functions without giving it a different name first.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Hey, good idea to use `ans`! I agree it's ugly, but the very purpose of code golf is to abuse language. As for your second proposal, I wouldn't know how many bytes to count then :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Processing, 40 bytes

```
print(join(sort(args[0].split("")),""));
```

Answer (score 1):

## jq, 20 bytes

```
explode|sort|implode
```

try it [here](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=explode|sort|implode&j=%22this%22)

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 27 bytes

```
%{([char[]]$_|sort)-join''}
```

Comment: Nicely done with taking pipeline input.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 47 bytes

```
$a=str_split($argv[1]);asort($a);echo join($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 135 bytes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
main(){std::string s;std::cin>>s;std::sort(s.begin(),s.end());std::cout<<s;}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c9d5c37c2783a23

I payed for what I used :P

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, but it may have something to do with this not being valid C++ because [`main()` must have an `int` return](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main)

Comment: @Tas The question doesn't specify that it must be strictly valid code. If it works, it works.

Comment: `payed` paid...

Answer (score 1):

## [pb](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pb) (INVALID), 179 bytes

```
^w[B!0]{w[B!0]{>}<t[B]^b[T]vb[0]<[X]<vb[B+1]^>}^w[B!0]{w[B!0]{>}<t[B]b[0]<[X]v[T+2]w[B!0]{>}b[T]<[X]^[Y+2]}vv<w[B!0]{>vw[B=0]{v}w[B!0]{>}<t[B]b[0]^[Y]<[X]w[B!0]{>}b[T]<[X]<b[B-1]}
```

Answers on this site are only considered valid if the language they're written in was available (e.g. there was an interpreter) at the time the question was posted. I didn't finish pb's interpreter until the day after, so this answer is just for fun and is ineligible to win (not that it was going to). That's also why I formatted the header of this answer incorrectly; I don't want to show up in the leaderboard snippet :)

Here's the code with comments, though I'm not sure they'll be helpful to anyone trying to decipher this. I just wrote them to keep my thoughts straight while writing the program, so they're kind of redundant and all over the place.

```
^w[B!0]{                     # while there's something at (0, -1)
    w[B!0]{>}<t[B]^b[T]vb[0] # move last byte of input up by 1
    <[X]<v                   # go to (-1, 0)
    b[B+1]                   # increase by 1
    ^>}                      # restart loop
^w[B!0]{                     # while there's something at (0, -2)
    w[B!0]{>}<t[B]b[0]       # save last byte of input and erase it
    <[X]                     # go to (0, -2)
    v[T+2]                   # go down T+2
    w[B!0]{>}b[T]            # go right until there's nothing there. write T
    <[X]^[Y+2]}              # restart loop
vv<w[B!0]{                   # while there's something at (-1, 0)
    >vw[B=0]{v}              # go down the X=0 column until you find something
    w[B!0]{>}<t[B]b[0]       # save the rightmost thing and erase it
    ^[Y]<[X]w[B!0]{>}b[T]    # add the thing you got to Y=0, to be outputted
    <[X]<b[B-1]}             # decrease (-1, 0) by 1 and repeat loop
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 23 bytes

```
puts gets.chars.sort*''
```

Splits string by empty regexp, sorts array, joins array.
Thanks to @MartinBüttner for 6 bytes :D

Answer (score 1):

## Brainfuck, 140 bytes

Probably not the winning post, but still it was fun :)

```
----------[++++++++++>>,----------]<<[[<<]>>>>[[<<[[-<+>]>>>+<<<]<[->+<]>>>>[-<-<+<->>>>>+<<]>>-[+<<<[-<<+>>]>>>]<<<]<[-<+>>+<]>>>]<<.[-]<<]
```

Explanation:

Program loads whole line and performs bubble sort. After each sort iteration prints and removes last character. It's always the smallest one, because bubble sort guarantees, that after every iteration the lowest value is in the end. Stops after removal of all characters.

```
#read line
----------[++++++++++>>,----------]<<

#MEMORY MODEL OF WHOLE PROGRAM:
# 0|0|?|0|?|0|?|0|?|0|0
#     C   C   C   C
# C-character from input

#iterate if there are characters
[
    #go to first letter
    [<<]>>

    #MEMORY MODEL OF TWO SORTED CHARACTERS:
    # 0|?|0|?|0|?|0|?
    # S L M R F   G
    # S - swap of left during left 0 check
    # L - left character
    # M - middle, difference between left and right
    # R - right character
    # F - flag, set if left was not 0
    # G - next flag, set if left was 0

    #sort two characters if there are at least two
    >>[        
        #while right is not 0
        [
            #if left is not 0
            <<[[-<+>]
                #set flag
                >>>+<<<
            #clean up after left's 0 check
            ]<[->+<]>

            #if flag is set, so left is not 0
            >>>[-
                #move 1 from left and right to the middle
                <-<+<->>>
                #set next flag
                >>+<<
            ]

            #if next flag is not set, so left was 0 
            >>-[+
                #transfer right to left
                <<<[-<<+>>]>>>
            ]

        #while right is not 0
        <<<]

        #distribute middle to left and right
        <[-<+>>+<]>

    #end if it was the last character
    >>]
    #write and clear last character
    <<.[-]
#end if no more characters
<<]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
{
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/@v//kozMYgA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/6v86/6OVSjIyi5V0FJQyMkvAdFJRfn4uiJGclOjs5JiWmqIUCwA).

Also works in [05AB1E (legacy)](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/@v//kozMYgA) or [2sable](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f@/@v//kozMYgA), which are older versions of 05AB1E.

**Explanation:**

```python
{  # Sort the characters of the (implicit) input-string
   # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Idris, 46 bytes

```
main:IO();main=putStr$pack$sort$unpack!getLine
```

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 79 bytes

```
t=table for c in({...})[1]:gmatch"."do t:insert(c)end t:sort()print(t:concat())
```

Obviously, I could save a few bytes if the string was already in a variable (say, `s`):

```
t=table for c in s:gmatch"."do t:insert(c)end t:sort()print(t:concat())
```

Comment: 64 bytes: [`s=io.read()t={s:byte(1,-1)}table.sort(t)print(s.char(unpack(t)))`](https://ideone.com/4faIPJ)

Comment: 64 is [probably the minimum](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?sort+characters#Lua), too.

Answer (score 0):

## Bash + coreutils (49 bytes)

Bash was not yet submitted, here is a script (needs to be in a file, as it recurses):

```
[ $1 ]&&(echo ${1::1};$0 ${1:1})|sort|tr -d '\n'
```

I just recursively output head, call the script with the tail of the word in order to  split the input word (`$1`) to single chars and then use `sort` util.

However I believe a shorter solution using bash+coreutils exists... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 91 bytes

```
a=table t={}for c in arg[1]:gmatch(".") do t[#t+1]=c end a.sort(t)print(a.concat(t))
```

Lua has no string sort function or split/explode function, so it was a struggle

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 35 Bytes

```
(print(apply str(sort(read-line))))
```

This will prompt the user for input, sort the characters, rejoin them back into a string and print it.

However, we can make it 3 bytes smaller if we allow the result to include quotations:

```
(pr(apply str(sort(read-line))))
```

`pr` is a debugging tool that prints the object it's given rather than its contents, so instead of showing `hist` in the console, it will show `"hist"`.

Answer (score 0):

## **C++, 101 Bytes**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;main(){string s;cin>>s;sort(s.begin(),s.end());cout<<s;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), 2 bytes

```
z:
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLqqwgDCh_wZKSjMxiCBsA)

Output as a list of characters. Add the `J` flag if you want a string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ṡ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSVBMCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PXRoaXMmZmxhZ3M9)

Built-in for "sort".