# Sign that word 2!

Tags: code-golf, string, sorting, word

## Sign that word 2!

Not that long ago, I posted a challenge called [Sign that word!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54945/sign-that-word). In the challenge, you must find the signature of word, which is the letters put in order (e.g. The signature of `this` is `hist`). Now then, that challenge did quite well, but there was one key issue: it was WAY too easy (see the [GolfScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54947/42003)). So, I've posted a similar challenge, but with more rules, most of which have been suggested by PPCG users in the comments on the previous puzzle. So, here we go!

### Rules

1. Your program must take an input, then output the signature to STDOUT or the equivalent in whatever language your using.
2. You are not allowed to use built-in sorting functions, so stuff like `$` in GolfScript is not allowed.
3. Multicase must be supported - your program must group letters of both uppercase and lowercase together. So the signature of `Hello` is `eHllo`, not `Hello` as you are given by the GolfScript answer on the first version.
4. There must be a free interpreter/compiler for your program, which you should link to.

### Scoring

Your score is your byte count. Lowest byte count wins.

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=55090;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),e.has_more?getAnswers():process()}})}function shouldHaveHeading(e){var a=!1,r=e.body_markdown.split("\n");try{a|=/^#/.test(e.body_markdown),a|=["-","="].indexOf(r[1][0])>-1,a&=LANGUAGE_REG.test(e.body_markdown)}catch(n){}return a}function shouldHaveScore(e){var a=!1;try{a|=SIZE_REG.test(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0])}catch(r){}return a}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){answers=answers.filter(shouldHaveScore).filter(shouldHaveHeading),answers.sort(function(e,a){var r=+(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[1/0])[0],n=+(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[1/0])[0];return r-n});var e={},a=1,r=null,n=1;answers.forEach(function(s){var t=s.body_markdown.split("\n")[0],o=jQuery("#answer-template").html(),l=(t.match(NUMBER_REG)[0],(t.match(SIZE_REG)||[0])[0]),c=t.match(LANGUAGE_REG)[1],i=getAuthorName(s);l!=r&&(n=a),r=l,++a,o=o.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",i).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",c).replace("{{SIZE}}",l).replace("{{LINK}}",s.share_link),o=jQuery(o),jQuery("#answers").append(o),e[c]=e[c]||{lang:c,user:i,size:l,link:s.share_link}});var s=[];for(var t in e)e.hasOwnProperty(t)&&s.push(e[t]);s.sort(function(e,a){return e.lang>a.lang?1:e.lang<a.lang?-1:0});for(var o=0;o<s.length;++o){var l=jQuery("#language-template").html(),t=s[o];l=l.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",t.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",t.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",t.size).replace("{{LINK}}",t.link),l=jQuery(l),jQuery("#languages").append(l)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",answers=[],page=1;getAnswers();var SIZE_REG=/\d+(?=[^\d&]*(?:&lt;(?:s&gt;[^&]*&lt;\/s&gt;|[^&]+&gt;)[^\d&]*)*$)/,NUMBER_REG=/\d+/,LANGUAGE_REG=/^#*\s*([^,]+)/;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table></div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table></div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Must lowercase and uppercase be ordered? For example, for `ThHihs`, can we output `hHhist` or do we have to output `hhHist` or `Hhhist`?

Comment: I cannot comprehend rule 3.

Comment: @Fatalize As long as they are grouped together, it doesn't matter. It can be any of those.

Comment: @feersum Try running the GolfScript answer on the first version of this challenge with the string "Hello" (without the quotes). Then you should see what I mean.

Comment: @Kslkgh I do not wish to install a GolfScript interpreter in order to understand the question. The requirements should be clearly specified in the question itself.

Comment: @feersum You don't need to. There is a link in the answer to an online interpreter. But I will make it clearer.

Comment: So what you really mean is that the sorting should be case-insensitive? Why not simply say so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27230/discussion-between-kslkgh-and-feersum).

Comment: Correctly handling lower/upper case in Unicode is scary, so is this question voluntarily limited to ASCII letters: [a-zA-Z]?

Comment: You forgot to close the parenthesis after "see this GolfScript answer". https://xkcd.com/859/

Comment: "Your score is your byte count." So I rank better when I have more bytes? Maybe you should update that one :P

Comment: @JonasDralle: remember, this is golf, where scoring is always backwards!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
sm@+drd1zG
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%40%2Bdrd1zG&input=Hello&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
             implicit: z = input string
 m       G   map each letter (variable d) of the alphabet to:
   +drd1        d + upper(d)
  @     z       filter z for these two letters
s            sum, join to a string
```

Answer (score 5):

## GOTO++, 531 bytes

```
niveaugourou 0
s=ENTRETONTEXTE()
§2 a=LeCaracNumero()&s *(1)
n=*(1)
costaud i=*(2)/&i infeg NombreDeLettres(&s)/i=+*(1)
b=LeCaracNumero()&s &i
c=&b
d=&a
GOTONULPOURLESNULS %4 }&b sup *(96){
c=-*(32)
§4 GOTONULPOURLESNULS %5 }&a sup *(96){
d=-*(32)
§5 GOTONULPOURLESNULS %1 }&c inf &d{
a=&b
n=&i
§1 faiblard
GOTOPRINTDUTEXTE()&a
s=Marijuana()}BOITEAPINGOUINS()}PrendsUnMorceau()&s *(0) &n{ }PrendsUnMorceau()&s }&n+*(1){ *(0){{ «»
GOTONONNULPOURLESNULS %3 }NombreDeLettres(&s) eg *(1){
GOTOPASMALIN %2
§3 GOTOPRINTDUTEXTE()&s
```

[GOTO++ Project page](http://www.gotopp.org/index.html.en)

Here's a slighlty more readable and commented version of the code(Note that `GOTO` starts a comment in GOTO++):

```
niveaugourou 0                                          GOTO Allow every keyword to be used
s=ENTRETONTEXTE()                                       GOTO Read from STDIN
§2 a=LeCaracNumero()&s *(1)                             GOTO Get first char in s
n=*(1)                                                  
costaud i=*(2)/&i infeg NombreDeLettres(&s)/i=+*(1)     GOTO Loop on every char of s
b=LeCaracNumero()&s &i                                  GOTO b = i-th char
c=&b                                            
d=&a
GOTONULPOURLESNULS %4 }&b sup *(96){                    GOTO If b is uppercase, goto §4 
c=-*(32)                                                GOTO Get the uppercase ASCII value of b
§4 GOTONULPOURLESNULS %5 }&a sup *(96){                 GOTO same as above but with a
d=-*(32)                                                
§5 GOTONULPOURLESNULS %1 }&c inf &d{                    GOTO If b is after a in alphabetical order, goto §1 (next loop iteration)
a=&b                                                    GOTO Else replace a by b
n=&i                                                                
§1 faiblard                                             GOTO End loop
GOTOPRINTDUTEXTE()&a                                    GOTO Print the value of a
t=PrendsUnMorceau()&s *(0) &n                           GOTO Get the part of s before a
u=PrendsUnMorceau()&s }&n+*(1){ *(0)                    GOTO Get the part of s after a
e=BOITEAPINGOUINS()&t &u                                GOTO Create an array of penguins containing the two substrings
s=Marijuana()&e «»                                      GOTO Concatenate the penguins in the array
GOTONONNULPOURLESNULS %3 }NombreDeLettres(&s) eg *(1){  GOTO If s is one char long, goto §3
GOTOPASMALIN %2                                         GOTO Else goto §2
§3 GOTOPRINTDUTEXTE()&s                                 GOTO Print the last char
```

Comment: Marks of a great programming language: all commands are in French and the official website says "Send your logo et look dumb."

Comment: @AlexA. Mark of a great programming language: `function(arg)` and `function() arg` are both valid. Also, priority brackets are `} {` and not the boring `( )`

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, <s>72</s> 70 bytes

```py
s=input()
print("".join(d*(ord(d)&31==c)for c in range(27)for d in s))
```

Assumes the input consists of only `[a-zA-Z]`.

*(-2 bytes thanks to @xnor)*

Comment: I think you can do `"".join(c*b ...)` for `"".join(c ... if b)`  the same way `sum(n ... if b)` can be `sum(n*b ...)`.

Comment: Collapsing the two loops into a single loop with a sentinel, and compressing the equality check: `c=1
for d in(input()+'~')*26:print(d[ord(d)&32^c:],end='');c+=d>'z'` (67)

Comment: @xnor I've added the first tip (thanks!) but I think you should post the second as a separate answer :)

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 51

```haskell
f s=[x|(a,b)<-zip['a'..'z']['A'..],x<-s,x==a||x==b]
```

The `zip` creates a list of pairs of characters `[('a','A'), ...('z','Z')]`. Because of truncation, the second endpoint doesn't need to be specified. For each pair in the list, we take the letters in the input string `s` that are either of the two characters in the pair.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <strike>15</strike> 14 bytes

```
s*V/LzJ.irG1GJ
```

Thanks for isaacg for removing 1 byte.

I don't know much about Pyth yet, so this may not be golfed well.

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jk*V%2FLzJ.irG1GJ&input=this&debug=0)

Comment: One easy golf: `s` is the same as `jk` on a list of strings.

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript, <strike>112</strike> 194 bytes

```
r=[];t=[];a=s.split('').map(function(x){t[i=parseInt(x,36)]?t[i].push(x):t[i]=[x];return i;});while(l=a.length)r[l-1]=t[a.splice(a.indexOf(Math.max.apply({},a)),1)].pop();console.log(r.join(''))
```

This is far away from "golfed" but I'm a bit busy right now, just editted to remove sort.

Comment: @frikinside While it might not help this solution since sorting was disallowed, Javascript ES6 arrow functions could help shorten this. (Not all browsers support ES6 yet, try Firefox). Maybe it'll help your future solutions though! :) An example of what it might look like: `console.log(input.split('').sort((a,b)=>a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase())).join(''))`

Comment: @UndefinedFunction Actually I choose to use plain javascript on purpose, for the "challenge" but thx a lot for the nice suggestion!

Comment: @edc65 actually I was aware of that in a previous comment (like u said) and I did not forget it, I wasn't have time until now.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 71 <s>74</s>

Limited to A-Za-z (see comment by @Matthieu M)

*Edit* Too used to compose a single expression with commas, to avoid 'return'. Here an output is required, so I can use a simple `for` and forget about commas.

<s>Using array comprehension the byte count is 73, but that is not valid EcmaScript 6 anymore</s>

Usual note: test running the snippet on any EcmaScript 6 compliant browser (notably not Chrome not MSIE. I tested on Firefox, Safari 9 could go)

```js
f=w=>{v=[];for(c of w)v[n=parseInt(c,36)]=(v[n]||'')+c;alert(v.join``)}
```

```html
<input id=I value='Hellzapoppin'><button onclick=f(I.value)>-></button>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3, 64

A small improvement on [Sp3000's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55125/20260), which uses the idea of iterating iterating the character indices, and for each one, iterating through the input to take characters that match up to case.

```python
c=1
for d in(input__+'~')*26:print(end=d[ord(d)&31^c:]);c+=d>'z'
```

This uses a single loop, looping through the input 26 times. The separator `~` is used to know when to go to the next character index `c`. To whether character `d` matches value `c` up to case, the last five bits of the bit-value of `d` are xor-ed with `c`, with a 0 indicating a match.

Then, the character `d` is printed exactly when the result is `0`, with an empty string otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>275</s> 270 bytes

```
<?php
for($i=65;$i<123;$i++){$v[$i]=chr($i);}foreach(str_split($argv[1])as$c){$a=array_search($c,$v);if($a<97){$p[]=($a+32);$z[]=$a;}else{$p[]=$a;}}foreach($p as$chr){$m=min($p);if($z[0]+32==$m){echo chr($m-32);unset($z[0]);}else{echo chr($m);}unset($p[array_search($m,$p)]);}
```

**Explanation:**

The code generates an array with every letter in the alphabet, which has its ASCII Value as Array Key. Afterwards the code generates a new array which contains the ASCII Values of the Input. Then the lowest Value gets printed out and gets removed.


**Usage:**

Call the script with an argument: `php -d error_reporting=0 script.php Hello`


**Ungolfed Version:**

```
<?php
$input = $argv[1];
$valueArray = [];
for($i=65;$i<123;$i++) {
    $valueArray[$i] = chr($i);
}
$new = str_split($input);
foreach($new as $char) {
    if(array_search($char, $valueArray)<97) {
        $newArray[] = (array_search($char, $valueArray)+32);
        $checkArray[] = array_search($char, $valueArray);
    } else {
        $newArray[] = array_search($char, $valueArray);
    }
}
foreach($newArray as $chr) {
    if($checkArray[0]+32 == min($newArray)) {
        $string .= chr(min($newArray)-32);
        unset($checkArray[0]);
    } else {
        $string .= chr(min($newArray));
    }
    $key = array_search(min($newArray), $newArray);
    unset($newArray[$key]);
}

echo $string;
```

Any advices are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Uppercase letters are not working ... need to fix this.

Comment: Fixed that the code also works when the Input has Uppercase letters.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2.7, <del>114</del> 106 bytes

```
l=[0]*123
for e in raw_input():l[ord(e)]+=1
print''.join(chr(j)*l[j]for i in range(26)for j in(i+65,i+97))
```

Logs the presence of a char in a 123 length array(for including both A-Z and a-z ranges) and then iterates through it to get the non-zero entries.
Inefficient, but more efficient than brute forcing it(but longer :().

Testing it-

```
<< HelloWorldhi
>> deHhillloorW
```

Comment: When I run it with `HelloWorldhi`, I get `['d', 'e', 'H', 'h', 'i', 'lll', 'oo', 'r', 'W']`

Comment: @muddyfish oops my bad. I pasted the wrong code while trying out a couple of things. Thanks for that :)

Comment: You don't need the `if l[j]` either.

Comment: @muddyfish Nice, they become empty strings(and are removed when `join`ed). -8 bytes. Thanks :)

Comment: You could replace raw_input with just input if your input is `'HelloWorldhi'` instead of `HelloWorldhi`.

Comment: @SirParselot Yeah, but that seemed like modifying the input as given in the question, so didn't do that

Comment: It doesn't say anything about it in the instructions, but it's your code so it's up to you

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>83</s> 53 bytes

```
import Data.Char
f y=[c|x<-[' '..],c<-y,toLower c==x]
```

Usage: `f "HelloWorldhi"` -> `"deHhillloorW"`.

How it works: let `y` be the input string

```
[ |x<-[' '..]                  ]  -- for every x from Space to the last Unicode character
             ,c<-y                -- loop through all character c from the input string
 c                ,toLower c==x   -- and keep those where the lowercase version equals x
```

Edit: 30 bytes saved, imagine that! Thanks @Mauris.

Comment: Why not just `import Data.Char;f y=[c|x<-[' '..],c<-y,toLower c==x]` (53 bytes)? (This will take some time to terminate, because `length [' '..] == 1114080` -- but it's finite.)

Comment: @Mauris: Wow! Btw: 8.5sec on a 4 year old laptop is not too long.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 61 bytes

A new answer for a different technique!

```
z=['']*42
for c in input():z[ord(c)&31]+=c
print(*z,sep='')
```

Noting that `ord('a')&31==ord('A')&31` and that `ord('z')&31==ord('Z')&31`, we can simply create an array of empty strings and for each character add it to the array index of its ASCII value `&31`. When you print it, it will be sorted.

Limited to input `a-zA-Z`.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 8 bytes

```apl
s⊇⍨⍋⌈s←⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97X/xo672R70rHvV2P@rpKH7UNuFR7zyQzH/ONC6P1JycfC4gI7HY2dMzOT8lFQA)

(If a function were OK, it would have been 5 bytes `⍋⍤⌈⊇⊢`.)

`⍋` can be controversial here, because the challenge says "built-in sorting functions not allowed" and `⍋`, called "Grade", is definitely related to sorting but it doesn't sort the input by itself. Instead, it gives a list of indices which, when used to index into the original input, results in the sorted array:

```apl
      x←10 50 20 40 75
      ⍋x
1 3 4 2 5
      x[⍋x]
10 20 40 50 75
```

This can be also used to implement "sort-by", if we index into a different array other than `x`:

```apl
      'abcde'[⍋x]
acdbe
```

#### How it works

```apl
s⊇⍨⍋⌈s←⍞  ⍝ Full program
     s←⍞  ⍝ Take a line of string input and assign to s
    ⌈     ⍝ Uppercase the letters
   ⍋      ⍝ Grade up; find the sorting order
s⊇⍨       ⍝ Index into the original string s,
          ⍝ essentially sorting the string in the case-insensitive order
```

If `⍋` is not acceptable:

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 12 bytes

```apl
∊⍞∘∩¨⎕A,¨⌊⎕A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM9DUh0Peqd96hjxqOOlYdWPOqb6qgDpHq6QCyQiv@caVweqTk5@VxARmKxs6dncn5KKgA)

Set intersection in APL is essentially "erase the items in the left argument that do not appear in the right argument", so the duplicates in the left argument is preserved.

#### How it works

```apl
∊⍞∘∩¨⎕A,¨⌊⎕A  ⍝ Full program.
     ⎕A,¨⌊⎕A  ⍝ Pair each char in ⎕A (uppercase letters) with its lowercase
 ⍞∘∩¨         ⍝ Take intersection of entire input and each pair of chars
∊             ⍝ Flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>97</s> 92 bytes

```
from itertools import*;print(*min(permutations(input()),key=lambda z:str(z).lower()),sep='')
```

The best way to sort is clearly to generate all permutations, and then pick the minimum, which just happens to be sorted :)

The strings are lowercased before comparison to abide by the 'case-aware' rules.

Warning: may be *very slow* with big strings.

An interpreter is located [here](http://repl.it/languages/Python3).

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 118 bytes

```
i=input();i,x=map(list,(i,i.lower()))
while x:q=min(x);x.remove(q);q=[q.upper(),q][q in i];i.remove(q);print(q,end="")
```

Could be golfed much shorter, I know

Comment: You can replace `if q not in i:` with `if~-(q in i):`.

Comment: I do because I'm calling the `.remove()` function on it.

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, 164 Bytes

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this, but I couldn't come up with anything else. Just takes the input as a character array, does an insertion sort, and spits out the output. Loses horribly, even to other non-golfing languages.

#### Code:

```
$a=[char[]]($args[0]);For($u=1;$u-lt$a.Count;$u++){$n=$a[$u];$l=$u;while(($l-gt0)-and((""+$a[$l-1]).CompareTo(""+$n)-gt0)){$a[$l]=$a[$l-1];$l--}$a[$l]=$n};$a-join''
```

#### Usage:

```
PS C:\scripts> .\sign-word-2.ps1 tTHhis
hHistT
```

#### Expanded & Explained:

```
$a=[char[]]($args[0])               # Takes command-line argument, recasts as char array
For($u=1;$u-lt$a.Count;$u++){       # Performs a quick-n-dirty insertion sort
  $n=$a[$u]
  $l=$u
  while(($l-gt0)-and((""+$a[$l-1]).CompareTo(""+$n)-gt0)){
  # Ugly, ugly code here. String.CompareTo(String) is case-insensitive, but
  # because we cast as a char[], Char.CompareTo(Char) is case-sensitive ...
  # So, need to do an on-the-fly re-casting as a string with ""+
    $a[$l]=$a[$l-1]
    $l--
  }
  $a[$l]=$n
}
$a-join''             # Without the -join'', it would print out the chars with a space between
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 61 bytes

```
f=s->s>""?(k=indmax([s...]%32);f(s[k+1:end]s[1:k-1])s[k:k]):s
```

Julia will display it as a string output if you call it in the REPL. If it *has* to print out to STDOUT, then it needs 78 bytes:

```
x->(f=s->s>""?(k=indmax([s...]%32);f(s[k+1:end]s[1:k-1])s[k:k]):s;print(f(x)))
```

An interpreter for Julia can be found [here](https://www.juliabox.org/). Another one, which I've already put some code into, is [here](http://goo.gl/d0YPnf). Note that, with the second one, you will need to make the terminal (at the bottom) visible by dragging the boundary up. Clicking "execute" will make it run in the terminal at the normal command line (and thus won't show the output if called without println). Alternatively, you can just type `julia` into the terminal itself, then handle everything inside the REPL that will come up.

And for a bit of extra fun, here are some other implementations

Gnome Sort (83 bytes):

```
s->(for m=2:endof(s),n=m:-1:2 s[n]%32<s[n-1]%32&&(s=s[[1:n-2,n,n-1,n+1:end]])end;s)
```

My own sorting algorithm (84 bytes):

```
s->(k=1;while length(k)>0 k=find(diff([s...]%32).<0);s=s[setdiff(1:end,k)]s[k]end;s)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 125 bytes

```java
s->{for(int i=s.length,j;i-->1;)for(j=i;j-->0;)s[i]^=(s[i]&95)<(s[j]&95)?s[j]^(s[j]=s[i]):0;System.out.print(new String(s));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY4xT8MwEIX3/IpTB2SjxioDA7gJQp2ZOkapZFwnOZPYkX0pqqr@9uCEEaZ77743fFZdVG7PXzMOow8ENnUxEfbiUWZ/fs3kNKF3/8JIwahhQbpXMcKHQge3DGCcPnvUEElROhePZxgSY0cK6NqqBhXayNcpwMG7OA0m7HWnQlWX0EAxx7y8NT4wdARYRNEb11K3tRLzvHySfGG2QGlT3UkeK6xPBVvOw8sz36dk1/S2hNNai4Xy1508XiOZQfiJxJh8iDnzDb9qLHIu77NcxRqhtDYjsQ11GDeC/CEZvoegrizN0uae3ecf)

Using a naive sort.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 82 bytes

```scala
print((""/:args(0)){case(s,c)=>val(a,b)=s.span(h=>{if(h<97)32 else 0}+h<c);a+c+b})
```

from command line:

```bash
$ scala -e 'print((""/:args(0)){case(s,c)=>val(a,b)=s.span(h=>{if(h<97)32 else 0}+h<c);a+c+b})' Hello
eHllo
```

probably can be golfed a bit further...
just implementing insertion sort using fold.

Answer (score 2):

## x86 machine code, <s>51</s> 42 bytes

```
00000000  b3 82 89 da 8b 07 80 fc  0d 74 12 b9 20 20 09 c1  |.........t..  ..|
00000010  38 e9 7e 06 86 c4 89 07  31 d2 43 eb e7 85 d2 74  |8.~.....1.C....t|
00000020  df c6 47 01 24 b4 09 cd  21 c3                    |..G.$...!.|
0000002a
```

Bubble sort, with some register reuse tricks to shave bytes here and there; the [.COM file](https://bitbucket.org/mitalia/pcg/downloads/sign.com) runs in DosBox, receives the input from command line and prints the output to standard output.

[image: sample session]

Commented assembly:

```
    org 100h

section .text

start:
    ; bubble sort - external loop
ext:
    ; start from the first character (assume bh=0, true on every DOS)
    mov bl,82h
    ; "not-swapped" flag - 82h => no swaps in current iteration;
    ; 0 => a swap happened (the 82h will come in handy later)
    mov dx,bx
    ; bubble sort - internal loop
int:
    ; read 2 characters at time in the full ax
    mov ax,word[bx]   ; al     ah
                      ; ^[bx]  ^[bx+1]
    ; check if we are at the end (the command line is CR terminated)
    cmp ah,0dh
    je skip
    ; make uppercase in cx
    mov cx,2020h
    or cx,ax
    ; compare
    cmp cl,ch
    jle next
    ; wrong order - swap and rewrite
    xchg al,ah
    mov word[bx],ax
    ; mark that we did a swap
    xor dx,dx
next:
    ; next character
    inc bx
    jmp int
skip:
    ; loop as far as we swapped something
    test dx,dx
    jz ext
end:
    ; $-terminate the string
    mov byte[bx+1],'$'
    ; print
    ; dx already contains the location of the string, since that's the
    ; flag value we used for "no swaps"
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 88 bytes

```
@_=/./g;a:{for(0..@_-2){@_[$_,$_+1]=@_[$_+1,$_],redo a if uc$_[$_]gt uc$_[$_+1]}}print@_
```

Just a simple Bubble Sort. Call with -n option to pass the text.

e.g:

```
echo "tThHiIsS" | perl -n sort2.pl
```

Output:

```
hHiIsStT
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 106 bytes

The code:

```
$c=count_chars($argv[1]);$r=str_repeat;for($i=64;++$i<91;)echo$r(chr($i),$c[$i]),$r(chr($i+32),$c[$i+32]);
```

There is nothing special in the code; [`count_chars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php) produces an array indexed by ASCII codes that contains the number of occurrences for each ASCII character. The rest is a dull iteration over this array.

Example of execution:

```
$ php -d error_reporting=0 sign.php qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPLKasdfJHGFDSAZXCVBNM
AaaBbCcDddEeFffGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSssTtUuVvWwXxYyZz
```

An extra byte can be saved using PHP 7: replace `$c[$i]` with `($c=count_chars($argv[1]))[$i]` and remove the assignment of `$c` from the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 74 bytes

```
l=(`mod`32).fromEnum
f=foldr(#)""
e#[]=[e]
e#a@(h:t)|l e<l h=e:a|1<2=h:e#t
```

Completely different from my [other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55139/34531). This time it's a simple Insertion sort.

Answer (score 1):

## Pip, <s>18</s> 14 bytes

[GitHub repository for Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip)

Seems there's no competing with Pyth, but this is pretty respectable.

```
FcAZ OcQUC_FIa
```

Works only on strings containing `a-zA-Z`. For each letter of the alphabet, uses a filter operation to grab the letters from the input string that equal that letter case-insensitively:

```
                    a <- cmdline arg, AZ <- string containing uppercase alphabet (implicit)
FcAZ                For each character c in AZ:
           FIa      Filter characters of a on the following lambda function:
      UC_           Uppercase of character...
         Qc         ... is equal to c
     O              Output the resulting list, joined on empty string by default
```

Two notes:

- The space is necessary; otherwise, the sequence `AZO` would scan as `A ZO` instead of `AZ O`;
- The program doesn't output a trailing newline. To add one, put an `x` at the end of the code (thereby printing an empty string after the loop is done).

Sample run (using the `x` variant):

```
dlosc@dlosc:~/pip$ pip -e "FcAZ OcQUC_FIax" "HelLo wOrld"
deHlLloOrw
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
œ.ΔlÇ¥dP
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6GS9c1NyDrcfWpoS8P9/SIZHZkYxAA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/o5P1zk3JOdx@aGlKwP9anf/RSiUZmcVKOgpKGZklYDqpKD8/F8RITkp0dnJMS00BcUIyPDIzwPIhqcUlBirqSrEA).

**Explanation:**

```python
œ         # Get all permutations of the (implicit) input-string
 .Δ       # Find the first permutation which is truthy for:
   l      #  Convert it to lowercase
    Ç     #  Convert each character to its ASCII codepoint
     ¥    #  Get the deltas / forward-differences of those codepoint integer
      d   #  Check that each difference is >= 0
       P  #  And check that all of them are truthy
          # (after which the found string is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;BíC ËpUèD
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O0LtQyDLcFXoRA&input=IkhlbGxvIg)

```
;BíC ËpUèD     :Implicit input of string U
;B             :Uppercase alphabet
  í            :Interleave
; C            :  Lowercase alphabet
     Ë         :Map each D
      p        :  Repeat
       UèD     :    Count of D in U
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 31 bytes

```perl
for$i(a..z){print grep/$i/i,@F}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0glUyNRT69Ks7qgKDOvRCG9KLVAXyVTP1PHwa32/3@P1Jyc/H/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@67oBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `g`, 5 bytes

```
Ṗ'⇩ÞṠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJnIiwiIiwi4bmWJ+KHqcOe4bmgIiwiIiwiSGVsbG8iXQ==)

7 bytes without the flag (`;h` at the end) or 6 bytes flagless (`Ṗ‡⇩ÞṠc`). This would otherwise output a list of the signature potentially repeated multiple times.

Things that sort things may be out of bounds, but things that check if things are sorted aren't.

### Explained

```
Ṗ'⇩ÞṠ
Ṗ     # From all permutations of the input
 '    # keep only those where:
  ⇩   #   lowercasing the permutation
   ÞṠ #   gives a sorted string
```

Comment: I'm curious as to how Vyxal determines a string is sorted without, in some way, sorting it?

Comment: @Shaggy you don't need to sort something to see if it's sorted. You can just check that each overlapping pair is in order.